# How to find the size of an array in binary?

Tags: c, objdump, binary

I'm currently learning RE and try to understand some basic c programs.

I've almost figure out some concepts, but right now i've no idea how to find the size of an array when i use objdump or gdb.

for example :

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  char buffer[64];               // <= Where i supposed to find the array size ?
  gets(buffer);                   
  printf("Buffer : %s",buffer);
  return 0;
}
```

Anyone can explain me how is it possible ?

Comment: Check the stack =)

Comment: There is a difference between dynamically allocated arrays (trivial to find), stack-based (which may or not may be harder) and static arrays. For the latter you *may* have to disassemble your entire program -- and even then you can not be sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no easy way to do this, C doesn't have a concept of array sizes (at execute time), so the size isn't stored anywhere. You'll have to read the assembly code and (try to) understand it.

Take the following program

```
extern void *malloc(int);
extern char *strcpy(char *dst, char *src);

char firstname[80];
char lastname[80];

int main(void) {
    int some_variable=1;
    char buffer[64];
    int some_other_variable=2;
    char *otherbuffer=malloc(100);
    gets(buffer);
    strcpy(firstname, "John");
    strcpy(lastname, "Doe");
}
```

and compile it with `cc -fno-builtin -O0 -o arraysize arraysize.c`. (I had to disable built-in functions to prevent gcc from short-circuiting malloc and strcpy, and i declared them myself instead of using the headers for the same reason. Also, without -O0, gcc omits stuff that's never used).

Then, use `objdump -d arraysize` and check the `main` function:

```
0000000000400554 <main>:
  400554:   55                      push   %rbp
  400555:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp

// This instruction tells you that the function needs 80 (0x50) bytes on the
// stack. This happens to be the same as the size of all local variables
// here, but might be higher as well if the function needs stack space for
// function arguments and the like.
  400558:   48 83 ec 50             sub    $0x50,%rsp


// This puts 1 and 2 into the integer variables. Note we now know they're
// located at -0x10(%rbp) and -0xc(%rbp) on the stack.
  40055c:   c7 45 f0 01 00 00 00    movl   $0x1,-0x10(%rbp)
  400563:   c7 45 f4 02 00 00 00    movl   $0x2,-0xc(%rbp)

// This calls malloc(100) and puts the result into -0x8(rbp). We now know
// the array pointed to has 100 bytes, because that's what was malloc'ed.
// Note that you have no other way of finding out the size afterwards
// (except if you know how exactly malloc is implemented and where malloc
// keeps its internal housekeeping structures)
  40056a:   bf 64 00 00 00          mov    $0x64,%edi
  40056f:   e8 b4 fe ff ff          callq  400428 <malloc@plt>
  400574:   48 89 45 f8             mov    %rax,-0x8(%rbp)

// now, we call gets, feeding it with -0x50(%rbp) as its parameter.
// As the next variable that's used on the stack is at -0x10(rbp), we can
// assume that the array has 0x40=64 bytes. This does not have to be true;
// for example, if the function declared 2 arrays of 32 bytes each, they'd
// be at -0x50(%rbp) and -0x30(%rbp), and if the function never used the
// one at 0x30(%rbp), there'd be no way for us to tell the difference.
  400578:   48 8d 45 b0             lea    -0x50(%rbp),%rax
  40057c:   48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
  40057f:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  400584:   e8 bf fe ff ff          callq  400448 <gets@plt>

// This is the strcpy to firstname. The address of firstname is at 0x6009e0.
// We don't know how large it is, as we haven't seen a variable behind it yet.
  400589:   be a8 06 40 00          mov    $0x4006a8,%esi
  40058e:   bf e0 09 60 00          mov    $0x6009e0,%edi
  400593:   e8 c0 fe ff ff          callq  400458 <strcpy@plt>

// And this is the second strcpy, to lastname at 0x6000980. Since we've
// seen the other strcpy to 0x60009e0, we assume that there are no more than
// 0x50=80 bytes in that buffer, but see below.
  400598:   be ad 06 40 00          mov    $0x4006ad,%esi
  40059d:   bf 80 09 60 00          mov    $0x600980,%edi
  4005a2:   e8 b1 fe ff ff          callq  400458 <strcpy@plt>

// end of function
  4005a7:   c9                      leaveq 
  4005a8:   c3                      retq
```

The C source code said

```
char firstname[80];
char lastname[80];
strcpy(firstname, "John");
strcpy(lastname, "Doe");
```

and from the address difference between the two `strcpy`s, we assumed an array size of 80. But note that the exact same instructions would have been generated in that case:

```
char name[160];
strcpy(name+80, "John");
strcpy(name, "Doe");
```

So if you don't have debugging symbols, all you get are assumptions.